# Build custom editor to UI elements

Tags: unity

I want to add some extra functions to editor inspector for UI.Button but, I can't setup my script in this way :-/ How can I write custom inspector for UI Objects ?
This is what I wrote:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[CustomEditor(typeof(UnityEngine.UI.Button))]
[CanEditMultipleObjects]
public class AlignmentEditor : Editor
{
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        base.OnInspectorGUI();

        EditorGUILayout.HelpBox("Test", MessageType.Info);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is it displaying at the moment with your listed code?

Comment: @Savlon nothing :-/

Comment: Isn't there a compile error since you didn't import UnityEditor namespace?